# Network driver didn't actually change to the new MAC

Tags: linux, mac-address

whenever I try to change my MAC address I get "Network driver didn't actually change to the new MAC!!" error. I have tried;

```
macchanger wlan0 down
macchanger -r wlan0
```

Output:

```
Current MAC:   xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (unknown)
Permanent MAC: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (unknown)
New MAC:       yy:yy:yy:yy:yy:yy (unknown)
Network driver didn't actually change to the new MAC!!
```

Comment: There are plenty of results when searching the internet for "Network driver didn't actually change to the new MAC!!". Have you checked any?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably running those commands without root privileges. Try running these commands with `sudo`, and let's see what happens.

```
ip link show
ip link set address 00:11:22:33:44:55 wlan0
ip link show
```

Ideally, take the interface down before changing it's MAC address.

```
ip link set dev wlan0 down
# change MAC...
ip link set dev wlan0 up
```